# Is it possible to implement Streaming in a custom WCF LOB Adapter?

Tags: biztalk, wcf-lob-adapter

The WCF LOB Adapter SDK creates skeleton code for getting started in the implementation of custom LOB Adapters. As part of this code, the following [IOutboundHandler](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.servicemodel.channels.common.ioutboundhandler.aspx) interface is implemented:

```
Message Execute (Message message, TimeSpan timeout);
```

Is it possible to implement streaming with Adapters built with the WCF LOB Adapter SDK? As far as I can tell, none of the builtin WCF Adapters that implement streaming are using the IOutboundHandler interface...

Answer (score 1):

According to [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms734675.aspx) Message class supports streaming. It doesn't hold a whole body but a reader or writer reference instead.